# Laravel Query Logic

Tags: php, laravel

I have problems with Laravel query.
So I have a table that have 4 properties that I need to check, and table looks like:

```
product_id | partner_id | employer_id | type
```

So `partner_id` is setted in `Config` and there can be multiple different partners, as well as products and employers,  `type` can be `white` or `black`. Employers are array so I need to check them with `whereIn` or `whereNotIn`.

So  what I need to check is, where `type` is `white`, and not current partner and not current employers to list all rows from that table.

So I did something like

```
ProductListing::whereNotIn('employer_id', $employers)
->where('type', 'white')
->where('partner_id', '!=', $partner_id)
->pluck('product_id')
->toArray();
```

But this query is not working as expected. I should probably check every row for `partner` and then list `whereNotIn`, but I have no idea how. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Can you try `pluck('product_id')->get()->toArray();`?

Answer (score 0):

Use where with a `!=` operator in combination with `whereNull`.

```
where('employer_id', '!=' , $employers)->orWhereNull('employer_id')
```

Comment: whereNull should not be in this query

Answer (score 0):

you can check [Basic Where Clauses in docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#basic-where-clauses) to see that inequality sign is `<>`

```php
// from docs
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->where('votes', '<>', 100)
                ->get();

// your fixed query 
ProductListing::whereNotIn('employer_id', $employers)
->where('type', 'white')
->where('partner_id', '<>', $partner_id)
// as you mentioned that you want to list all suitable rows,not just product ids
->get();
```